Есть ли способ обойти ограничение на загрузку статей telegraph?
Я работаю с библиотекой Telegraph. Сделал автоматическое создание статей, заполняемых информацией из базы данных.
Но в один момент срабатывает ограничение Try again later и приходится около 10 минут ожидать, чтобы удалось продолжить. Срабатывает ограничение примерно через каждые 10-20 публикаций.
Если прервать скрипт и включить/выключить VPN на пк (1.1.1.1 WARP+), то ограничение обходится, но затем можно его заново словить и нужно снова вручную переключать VPN.
Есть ли возможность автоматизировать обход ограничений публикаций или спама?
На данный момент, я справляюсь с проблемой бесконечным циклом, пока не получится опубликовать, но ждать в любом случае приходится, а это сильно замедляет процесс.

Если нужен код проекта, могу на github закинуть, но смысла нет, суть в вопросе описана.

Вероятно это ограничение самого телеграма, попробуйте делать паузу после публикации каждой статьи, допустим 1-2 минуты

Я не использую telegram, это telegraph. Хотя, как я понимаю, сервера могут быть одни и те же, так как одна компания.  Сделать паузу в 1-2 минуты сделает общее время ожидания значительно дольше. Допустим 20 публикаций умножить на 2 минуты = 40 минут ожидания, вместо 10 минут раз в 20 статей.  Я уже пытался сделать подобные решения, но это ошибка в любом случае встретится и замедлит работу.

То есть, телеграф это не апи обертка для телеграма, а что-то совершенно отдельное и никак не связанное с телеграмом? Или все же это всего лишь интерфейс для взаимодействия с телеграмом и ограничения самого телеграма влияют на все проекты которые используют его апи?

Насколько я знаю, telegraph - это полностью отдельная платформа. Изначально в телеграме не было возможности открывать статьи не переходя в браузер, это добавили в последствии. А для пк версии и вовсе только в этом месяце добавили интеграцию.
В любом случае, это к делу не имеет отношения, так как не влияет на проблему.
Дополнительное ожидание - не выход.
